# In $Z_{p^e}^*$, why is $p$-adic presentation of $x = \sum_{i=0}^{e-1} x_i p^{i}$, why is $g^{p_e(x_1 + \dots + x_{e_1} p^{e-2})} = 1$

Tags: group-theory, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

During studying for a cryptography course, I encountered the following formula in a section about calculating discrete logarithm in a group $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$. Assume that $n= p^e$ for some prime. Let $g$ be the generator of the group.

Then we can do the following to calculate $x = \log_{g}(h)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$, for some some $h = g^x \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$

1. Transform $x$ into the p-adic representation.
   $$x = x_0 + x_1 p^1 + x_2 p^2 \dots + x_{e-1} p^{e-1}$$ with $x_i < p$
2. Calculate sequentially $x_0, \dots, x_{e-1}$.

The script then claims that $x_0$ is the logarithm of $h^{p^{e-1}}$ to the basis of $g^{p^{e-1}}$ (all calculations $\mod n$), because
$$h p^{e-1} =  g^{x p^{e-1}} = g^{x_0 p^{e-1}} g^{p^e (x_1 + x_2 p + \dots x_{e-1} p^{e-2})} = (g^{p^{e-1}})^{x_0} \mod n$$

where $g^{p^e (x_1 + x_2 p + \dots x_{e-1} p^{e-2})} = 1 \mod n$ because of Fermat's Theorem. This is what I don't get: Why is the order of the group $\mathbb{Z}_*^n$ equal to $p^e (x_1 + x_2 p + \dots x_{e-1} p^{e-2})$ (this is what would need to be the case to be able to use Fermat's theorem, right?

Also, the script claims that the order of $g^{p^{e-1}}$ is $p$. Why is that?

Comment: What are $g$ and $h$?

Comment: $g$ is generator of the group and $h$ is the number we want to have the logarithm of $h = g^x$. Sorry, that was missing - I edited the post.